# how to always keep two divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I have two divs floating left. I dont really want to use position absolute though, is there another way to keep the side by side without using position absolute? or is this the only way?

```
<div class="moreinfo" id="darkgray">
            <p>
                Today, hate speech continues to profilerate throughout the Internet, normalized in the form of YouTube comments, animated GIFs, and tweets. Online anonymity affords users a sense of security that fosters a culture of cruelty and bigotry. Our goal is to create a conversation about the consequences of hateful speech that rethinks how we communicate online. Social media is full of positive potential; we can tap into it by holding each other accountable.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="moreinfo" id="lightgray">
            <h2>
                "WE NEED TO TEACH OUR CHILDREN NOT TO STAND SILENTLY BY WHILE OTHERS ARE BEING TORMENTED. IN THE END, THEY WILL BE SAFER ONLINE &amp; OFFLINE."
                <a href="#">READ ARTICLE BY WIRED SAFETY</a>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
```

**css**

```
.moreinfo{
    width:715px;
    height:250px;
    float:left;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: `display: inline-block` may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best way i noticed was to use percent 50% for the width of both

Comment: Please mark the most upvoted answer as correct. That is a better and complete answer.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `display: inline-block` to have them side by side.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/2sZCb/

```
.moreinfo {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is a good article on the same issue you're having:
http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/

Comment: thank you for the article this is great adding display:inline-block; however did not fix the problem does it have to work with percents only? I do not want them to scale i would rather have the window crop it out.

Answer (score 0):

the css you have written is work correctly for keeping div side by side, but you have to take precaution about the width of the inner floating divs, it should not be greater than the parent's width.
try this (reduce the width of the moreinfo just for demo.):

```
.moreinfo{
width:150px;
height:300px;
float:left;
color:black;}
```

Answer (score 0):

the best solution is using `display:table` and `display:table-cell` for being sure that they are side by side

Comment: there are compatibility concerns with this.  It's not a huge percentage but those with IE7 and below are affected.  http://caniuse.com/css-table

Comment: lol reading that in my head was the funniest thing just now.  so much excitement with the punctuation

Answer (score 0):

Set the containing element to a width large enough to contain both the way you want.

```
body {
  min-width: 1450px;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XQF6J/)